# Acer windows 7 - I can not download updates and I can not install McAfee program

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus

My installed McAfee program kept telling me it wasn't receiving updates and that I wasn't protected. I uninstalled it but now I find I'm unable to reinstall it. I can also see that Windows Update has stopped working.

I am at my wits end - I've tried so many things (clearing Internet cookies etc - running a repair program) but to no avail.

I don't think I have a virus.

When I try to download the McAfee program it gets through all of the updates but right at the end says there was a problem and to use the virtual technician. The virtual technician tells me that the error is: Problem:clear temp folders - I have done this but am still having problems.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Uninstall McAfee, install Security Essentials...http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See my post in this thread to clean the system of malware using a Boot CD (Alternate Method)

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533)